# Assign SQL result set to several variables

Tags: c#, sql

I am coding a Sharepoint 2010 Web Part and need to get a result set from SQL server and assign the results to five different variables in C#. My select is as follows:

```
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
    FROM Table
    WHERE Id = 1
```

I want the results of this statement assigned to 5 different variable:

```
    var result1 = col1
    var result2 = col2
    var result3 = col3 
    var result4 = col4
    var result5 = col5
```

I know how to the ExecuteScalar method in cases where I am returning one item from my query but how do i achieve a similar operation from the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accomplish this.

Sample usage:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              result1 = reader[0];
              result2 = reader[1];
              // etc.
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a detailed example on how to use this method?

Comment: Just Google around for how to use ExecuteReader().

Comment: You're welcome. If you know the datatypes of your columns you can use the `Get*()` methods of the `SqlDataReader` class. See here for an example of one of those methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx